# How to change color of divisions in Slider flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, slider, division

Hello i have slider with divisions. What is the theme property for changing divisions color so they are not visible?

Comment: it was enough to set inactiveColor: Colors.blue, to make all slider all color. 
But just in case I would like to know which property changes only devisions color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see this example and let me know if you need any further help :

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    trackHeight: 10.0,
    minThumbSeparation: 2,
    thumbColor: Colors.white,
    thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
    overlayColor:Colors.deepPurple,
    inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.amber,
    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  child: Slider(
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    value: 45,
    divisions: 2,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      // set the new value here
      setState(() {
        progress= newValue;
      });
    },
  ),
)
```

Let's demonstrate some params:

1. **The Main Param for changing the color of the divisions is inactiveTickMarkColor param in SliderTheme object which is amber in our case.**
   Feel free to change it as you want.
2. The inactiveTrackColor param is the color of the slider when the area is not in the active rang.
3. The overlayColor param is the color of the widget that appears when you press or focus on the selector widget.

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap you slider with **SliderTheme** widget and then adding **SliderThemeData** to it, inside **SliderThemeData** ,
where **TickMark** defines division,
you would find properties for changing **TickMark** color,
here is an example

```
                                              data: SliderThemeData(
                                                activeTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                inactiveTickMarkColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                thumbColor: ColorAssets.themeColorMagenta,
                                                activeTrackColor: ColorAssets.themeColorMagenta,
                                                inactiveTrackColor: Colors.white,
                                              ),
                                              child: Slider(
                                                value: textSliderValue,
                                                min: 0,
                                                max: 20,
                                                divisions: 20,
                                         
                                          ),
                                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change ColorScheme's primary color to change slider's color, but it requires to assign value of all colors.

```
colorScheme: ColorScheme(
        primary: Colors.amber,
        primaryVariant: Colors.amber,
        secondary: Colors.amber,
        secondaryVariant: Colors.amber,
        surface: Colors.amber,
        background: Colors.amber,
        error: Colors.amber,
        onPrimary: Colors.amber,
        onSecondary: Colors.amber,
        onSurface: Colors.amber,
        onBackground: Colors.amber,
        onError: Colors.amber,
        brightness: Brightness.light),
```